# Convert Sub-Query with "not in" operator to join

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery

Is it possible to convert a sub-query with NOT IN operator to join? I need this query using joins

```
SELECT *
FROM Contacts
WHERE ContactIntID NOT IN(
    SELECT LinkToIntID
    FROM Requirements
    WHERE Requirements.uuJobStatus = 'Open')
```

Comment: If you want efficiency and no Null troubles, use `NOT EXISTS`: **[Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)**

Comment: As per my knowledge joins perform better than sub-queries. So wanted to avoid sub-queries and use joins. Thought co-related sub-queries are also a kind of sub-queries only which would be having less performance and hence asked only for joins.

Comment: I know, this is a common misunderstanding. It seems strange indeed but with proper indexes, NOT EXISTS is almost always the winner. However, if you read the article carefully, it states in the end: **"But, as always, you need to test these patterns in your own environment, using your schema, data and hardware, and mixed in with your own workloads."**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using non exists will generally perform better than using LEFT JOIN. With the above answers,
the contacts will join all records regardless whether they match or not, and then filter them out later using the IS NULL clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM Contacts c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Requirements r
    WHERE Requirements.uuJobStatus = 'Open'
    AND ContractIntID = r.LinkToIntID
)
```

Edit: Realised you wanted a non sub query, but nevertheless worth noting my reply :)

Answer (score 17):

Yes.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Contacts c
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT LinkToIntID FROM Requirements WHERE uuJobStatus='Open') r 
  ON (c.ContactIntID=r.LinkToIntID)
WHERE r.LinkToIntID IS NULL
```

and simplified:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Contacts c
LEFT JOIN 
  Requirements r 
  ON  r.uuJobStatus = 'Open'
  AND c.ContactIntID = r.LinkToIntID
WHERE r.LinkToIntID IS NULL
```

Comment: genuis solution x years later

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Contacts C LEFT JOIN Requirements R
ON C.CommonField = R.CommonField
WHERE R.CommonField IS NULL AND R.uuJobStatus = 'Open'
```

Comment: It is always best practice not to use(if possible) NOT IN operator as NOT IN operator checks all the rows in a table against the condition given in NOT IN operator which makes Existence of indexes irrelevant and query performance can be really painful :)

Comment: This query is wrong - not equivalent to the one in the question. It will return exactly zero rows - whatever data the tables may have.